# how to use Node.js connect-memcached middleware

Tags: node.js, session, memcached, connect

There is a simple example about how to use [connect-memcached](https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached).

```
var express      = require('express')
, session        = require('express-session')
, cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser')
, http           = require('http')
, app            = express()
, MemcachedStore = require('connect-memcached')(session);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
      secret  : 'CatOnKeyboard'
    , key     : 'test'
    , proxy   : 'true'
    , store   : new MemcachedStore({
        hosts: ['127.0.0.1:11211']
    })
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.session.views) {
        ++req.session.views;
    } else {
        req.session.views = 1;
    }
    res.send('Viewed <strong>' + req.session.views + '</strong> times.');
});
```

By this way, we can use Memcached to store our session.
But in this sample, i doubt that how Memcached store session in it (No code operating Memcached).
when we call `req.session.views = 1;` is the value `views` stored into Memcached right now? or it is not stored at all? can somebody explain this for me? or just teach me how to set and get session using Memcached here.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is saved at session for every call you do to server. But to check if session is the same and show the right value, the server need to check the session, when memcached works.
The get code check if have views on your session and increase 1 every time you call it.